# Django celery beat with Django as backend

Tags: django, django-celery

I'm trying to set up [Django-celery-beat](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#django-celery-beat-database-backed-periodic-tasks-with-admin-interface) in order to create periodic tasks.
My configuration is as follows:

```
from celery import Celery
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'config.settings.local')
celery = Celery(broker="django-db")
celery.autodiscover_tasks()

CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULER = 'django_celery_beat.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'
```

I'm trying to use Django as database and run both the beat service and the workers.

When I launch the workers like this:

```
celery -A monitoring worker --loglevel=DEBUG --app=config.settings.local
```

... I get:

```
ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@django-db:5672//: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known.
```

And when I try it when beat:

```
celery -A monitoring beat -l info --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler --app=config.settings.local
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR/MainProcess] beat: Connection error: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known. Trying again in 4.0 seconds...
```

I'd like to be able to create periodic tasks through the Django admin but I'm stuck at this point so any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think you also have to add settings for `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND`. Set it to `'django-db'` like you did with the broker. If that is not enough try setting the broker in the settings with `CELERY_BROKER_URL` instead of as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `django-db` as broker, where celery thinks it is a host address. You should use a real broker address (for e.g. `amqp://ip-or-host-here` for rabbitmq) instead. Try setting [broker_url](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#broker-url) and remove the broker argument in `Celery()` to point it to the right direction.

Comment: Hi @hurturk, given that I'm using django-celery-beat what's the point of using rabbitmq when I want to use Django as backend?

Comment: Afaik, `django-db` is not a broker but configured for result backend purposes. You still need a broker.